# Разбор слова по составу

Tags: морфемы

Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли я выполнила задание:

(в - приставка, любл - корень, ённ - словообразующий суффикс, ый - окончание, влюблённ - основа).

(от - приставка, мир - корень, а - словообразующий корень, ющ - формообразующий суффикс, ая - окончание, отмира - основа).

(раз - приставка, драж - корень, ённ - словообразующий суффикс, ый - окончание,  раздражённ - основа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Влюблённого (в - приставка, любл - корень, ённ - ФОРМОобразующий суффикс (форма причастия), -ОГО - окончание, влюбл - словообр. основа).

Отмирающая (от - приставка, мир - корень, а - словообразующий СУФФИКС, ющ - формообразующий суффикс, ая - окончание, отмира - основа).

Раздражённый (раз - приставка, драж - корень, ённ - ФОРМОобразующий суффикс (образует глагольную форму - причастие), ый - окончание, раздраж - основа).

**В глаголе представлены следующие формообразующие суффиксы:**

1) инфинитив  -ть / -ти: чита-ть, нес-ти. У инфинитивов на —чь возможны два пути выделения флексии: пе-чь или печь-Ø, где Ø — нулевой формообразующий суффикс (исторически в чь наложились конец основы и собственно инфинитивный показатель).

2) прошедшее время изъяв.- суффикс -л— (дела-л— ) и -Ø-:

3) эти же суффиксы представлены в условном наклонении: дела-л-Ø бы, нёс-Ø— бы.

4) повелительное наклонение образуется суффиксами —и- (пиш-и— ) и -Ø— (делай-Ø-¤, сядь-Ø-¤).

5) причастие как особая форма глагола  -ащ-(-ящ-), -ущ-(-ющ-), -ш-, -вш-, -им-, -ом— / -ем-, -нн-, -онн— / -енн-, -т-: бег-ущ-ий, взя-т-ый

6) деепричастие как особая форма глагола  -а(-я), -в, -ши, -вши, -учи(-ючи): делаj-я, буд-учи.

7) простая сравнит. степень прилагательного и наречия  -е (выш-е), -её / -ей (быстр-ее), -ше (рань-ше), -же (глуб-же);

8) простая превосходная степень сравнения прилагательного  -ейш— / -айш— (быстр-ейш-ий, высоч-айш-ий).

Comment: Но это - одно мнение, когда нужна именно словообразовательная основа. В методиках, где считают за основу слова часть слова без окончания, только -ТЬ и -Л- не входят в основу.